# How Limit Session Pool Airflow OracleHook

Tags: python, oracle, airflow

I am using airflow with [OracleHook](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.13/_modules/airflow/hooks/oracle_hook.html) to do poolling in a database.
I performed the connection configuration using [oracle connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-oracle/stable/connections/oracle.html) through the graphical interface.

When executing the first dag, during the select, approximately 100 sessions were created.
I was able to track this by monitoring the oracle table.

```
SELECT *
FROM v$session;
```

I would like to pass some configuration to oracle or to the hook that can limit the maximum value of the connection pool or sessions with the database to a maximum of 20 for example.

Here is a snippet from my DAG:

```py
args = {
    'owner': 'dekstra',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'retries': 1
}

dag = DAG(
    'documents',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=2),
    default_args=args
)

listing = PythonOperator(
    task_id='listing',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=DocumentsService.listing,
    dag=dag
)

listing
```

```py
class DocumentsService:

    @staticmethod
    def listing(**kwargs):
        data = [column[0] for column in
                OracleHook(oracle_conn_id='oracle_connection').get_records(sql=DocumentsQuery.listing())]

        logger.info("Remaining Documents: {}".format(len(data)))

        shuffle(data)

        return data[:50]
```

I am using the `cx_Oracle` library in conjunction with `OracleHook`, it is possible to limit the session pool as specified [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connpool), but I do not know how to pass this configuration to `OracleHook`

Comment: Can you please share your dag code using hook?

Comment: Of course, I added more information in the description